# Como cancelar um handler?

Tags: android

Tenho esse Código

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (garagem.isChecked()!= luzgaragem){
                        garagem.setChecked(luzgaragem);
                        //Quando chegar aqui parar tudo

                    }else {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                        System.out.println("estou aqui");
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Como posso criar um loop e parar ele quando der if verdadeiro ??

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seguinte código dentro da `run()`:

```
while(true) {
  if(garagem.isChecked() != luzgaragem) {
    garagem.setChecked(luzgaragem);
    wait(); //Quando quiser que ele volte a executar, basta executar um notify ou notifyAll
  } else {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    System.out.println("estou aqui");
  }
}
```

Comment: COnsegui tambem com esse comando 
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Comment: @Guilherme Com essa linha, a alteração é irreversível. Usando o meu exemplo, é reversível.